# Phone menu css problems

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

Tried to customize phone menu with css, but it doesn't work very well.

The WP Theme support doesn't always work very well and sometimes too slow, so I gave it a shot here. I've solved a lot of problems, but I can't get these things to work. Tried different solutions to no avail.

Problems:

The logo goes down for a short while when scrolling. (picture added) But this problem seems to be inherent someway else. Even when I take away the custom CSS, the original menu area seems to have the same behaviour. (The theme support won't even acknowledge that this problem exists.)

The click area doesn't match the logo. (I need the logo to be clickable and work as home button.)

The menu shows up if you click besides the logo.

The cart shows twice in drop down menu. I only want it once.

I would rather have the submenu as a submenu and not just all menu links together in one row.

Here's the code and result. Any answers appreciated.

code:

```
header {
    margin: -5px 0 0 0; padding: -5px 0 0 0; !important}
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wpc-custom-mobile-menu-item .et-cart-info {
    display: block!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.et_header_style_centered .mobile_menu_bar {position: relative; height: 15px;}
.et_header_style_centered .mobile_nav .select_page, .et_header_style_split 
.mobile_nav .select_page {display: none; !important ;}
div#et_top_search {
    margin: -9px auto 0 !important;
}
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
.mobile_menu_bar:before{
color:#ffffff;
}
.et_header_style_centered #et_top_search {
display: block !important;
float: right !important;
}
.container
{
 margin-top: 15px !important;
  width:98% !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
#et_top_search {
margin: 22px 55px 0 0;
}
}

@media (max-width: 980px) { 
div#et_top_search {
z-index: 99999;
}
.et_search_outer {
display: block !important;
}
.et_header_style_centered #main-header .et_search_outer .container {
max-width: 80% !important;
}
.et_pb_menu_hidden div#et-top-navigation {
opacity: 0;
}
div#et_top_search {
    margin: -8px 11px 0 !important;
}
div#et_mobile_nav_menu {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: -35px;
}

.et_header_style_centered #main-header .mobile_nav {
    background: transparent !important;
}
header#main-header {
    height: 67px;
}

.et_pb_menu_hidden #logo {
    opacity: 0;
}

input.et-search-field {
    top: 0 !important;
}

span.et_close_search_field {
    top: 0 !important;
}
html.js {
    margin-top: auto !important;
}


header#main-header {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.select_page {
display:none !important;
}

.et_header_style_centered .mobile_menu_bar {
    top: 8px !important;
    left: 5px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 560px) {
div#et_mobile_nav_menu
{
   top: -36px !important;
}
.et_header_style_centered #main-header .mobile_nav {
    padding: 0px 10px !important;
}
div#et_top_search {
    margin: -9px auto 0 !important;
}
#et_top_search {
width:42px !important;
}
}

@media (min-width: 467px, max-width: 560px){
.container {
    margin-top: 15px !important; 
}
}

@media (max-width: 467px){
.container {
    margin-top: 0 !important; 
}
```

[phone menu problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvNQT.jpg)